# What's the best workflow for creating gerber files from, say, an HFSS project?

Tags: rf, eaglecad, layout, kicad

I am curious how everyone gets their RF/microwave designs from their preferred simulation/design suite (HFSS is just an example) into a gerber file for fabrication.

What's a good workflow, including programs you use and tricks & tips?

The real problem for me has been that a lot of the RF designs I work on have a lot of shapes and/or fills that aren't able to be natively re-drawn in PCB software like Eagle or kicad.

I can usually export a DXF, but complex objects just seem to export to a polyline, which cannot be filled in either kicad or Eagle, to my knowledge.

I suppose the krux of my problem is a duplicate of: [How to create complex copper shapes in Eagle](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/100187/how-to-create-complex-copper-shapes-in-eagle) , but I didn't want to limit the question to Eagle if someone has a better solution to the problem.

Comment: This isn't as well formed as it could be.  You're not really interested in Gerber output.  You need to get your images into  Eagle as part of the board.  Once there, (as in any of these packages) the Gerber is easy.  Suggest you retitle accurately.

Comment: AWR and ADS can create gerber files. DXF/DWG is common for 3D structures and GDSII for 2D layers.

Comment: Huh?  What's "HFSS"?

Comment: A 3d field solver

Answer (score 1):

The method I have sucessfully used is as follows:

1) Export DXF from HFSS

2) import DXF into Turbocad - smash down to ensure that the DXF consists only of the polyline primitive type.  Also I use the join polyline function in Turbocad to ensure the polygon is closed.  You may have problems with enclosed holes (like anulus) which may require to be split as two polygons.

3) Import processed DXF into GC Prevue (not the free version, but the puchased one that allows conversion) - available quite cheaply, only $100 or so.

4) Export from GC Prevue as gerber.

I have also imported directly a DXF consisting purely of primitives into Pulsonix (my preferred PCB tool) and PADS - although you may have to specify the DXF as being a filled shape.

Not being an Eagle user, I can't help you with this particular tool, I'm afraid.